# How to remove the words that are contain within some tags in R

Tags: r

Suppose A is a data frame and structure of A is as follows

```
Row no                           C1                                                  
1                               <p>I'd like to check if an uploaded file is </p> 

2                               <p>Is there a way to</p>

3                               <p>I am import matlab file and construct</p> <pre><code>Error in model.frame.default(formula = expert_data_frame$t_labels ~ .,</code></pre>
```

For the column C1 what I am doing is using the tm package I am turning the rows to corpus and then using the different function like removewhitespace, removesopwords. But how to remove the words withing a specific tags. In the above example I want to remove the words that are within the (code)--(/code) tags but unable to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to use an HTML parser.  That requires more explanation.  You can also get this done in an incorrect way with the qdap package:

```
library(qdap)
genX(A$C1, "<code>", "</code>")

## [1] "<p>I'd like to check if an uploaded file is </p>"        
## [2] "<p>Is there a way to</p>"                                
## [3] "<p>I am import matlab file and construct</p> <pre></pre>"
```

Comment: Here's a link that explains a little: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not  I actually don't care as my time is worth something and I can do the regex in simple cases faster than the HTML parse.  So I do it dirty sometimes and enjoy the rest of my day.

Comment: @tanay this one's a bit more entertaining http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

At a pinch, you could do:

```
A$C1 <- gsub('<code>.*?</code>', '', A$C1)
```

However, **there are many caveats to parsing HTML with regular expressions**.
For example, if I had the a string ' `# this is a`  tag ', the last ' tag ' would *not* be stripped.

If I adjusted the regex to use `.*` instead of `.*?` to get around this, the string ' `some code` and some text and  `some more code` ' would have *everything* stripped from it, even the (legitimate) text between the two code blocks.

What it boils down to is what you know about `A$C1`. Can you rely on it to not have more than one code block in one string (or more than one occurence of `</code>`)? Then use `<code>.*</code>`. Can you rely on the string '' *never* appearing within a code block? then use `<code>.*?</code>`.

If you really want to be sure, you can actually *parse* the XML with the `XML` package (can you rely on the contents of `A$C1` to be well-formed HTML, i.e. no missing tags?).

Comment: I think there will be no missing tags. The code will always be inside the <code> </code> tags. But can't be sure if there will be one code block or the string '' will not appear.